# DataTables - Column render call twice

Tags: datatables

I'm very new to Datatables plugin and i'm using it for my small project. I have the following problem like this: 
 + I want to create a table and each row have a link to pop up a modal for editing. 
Currently my datatables implementation as follow:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dtTable').DataTable({
        serverSide: false,
        processing: true,
        deferRender: true,
        ajax: {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetClasses", "CLASSes")',
            dataSrc: ""
        },
        columns: [
               { data: 'CLASSID' },
               { data: 'CLASSCODE' },
               { data: 'CLASSNAME' },
               {
                   orderable: false,
                   searchable: false,
                   render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                       debugger;
                       var data = full.CLASSID;
                       return '<a href="callModal()">Action</a>';
                   }
               }
        ]
    });
})
```

The problem is that when ever i click on the Action link the modal will appear and then disappear instantly, place a debugger at the render section it's seemed that this section call twice and i don't know why? 
So please help me to achieve this, each row has its link to pop up a modal and when click on it.
Thanks you guys very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery DataTables plug-in indeed calls [`render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) multiple times: for data type detection, display, sorting, etc.

Use the following code to produce content for display only:

```
render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
    if(type === 'display'){
        data = '<a href="callModal()">Action</a>';
    }

    return data;
}
```

Regarding modal dialogs, most likely there is a problem somewhere else in your code that makes the modal dialog disappear.

Comment: For me, inside render: that type === 'display' calls twice..  I am using latest version of library as of now.. Any more clue ?

Comment: @HiteshRiziya, that is normal, it's called multiple times for sorting, filtering, display and type detection, see [`render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option for more details.

Comment: @HiteshRiziya: what should I do, if I want render should get called once only? As I am doing some calculation in render method.

Comment: @SandeepKokate, I would advise against calculations in `render`. But if you put your code inside `if` statement as shown above, it should be called only once.

Comment: I have the same issue. With `type==="display"` it gets called twice when table is initiating. Second time is called after elements are already present in DOM. Later, on filtering and sorting, it gets called only once..

Comment: @Emptyfruit, it is possible some DataTables plug-ins could call `render`. Use [`columns.createdCell`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) option to define a callback function that will be called only once when a cell is created.